# loop through a dataframe with times and perform an operation if time is less than current time

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, while-loop

Updated info 06.12.20:
I am trying write a code where i loop through a dataframe and if an "index_time" is less than current time, then perform an operation, otherwise wait some time and loop again, until the end of the dataframe. the result of the code only works on the first row of the dataframe and then never finishes......

Her is my input data example.

```
  time_interval     index_time  flag
    10.0    1607279511.1    1
    10.1    1607279521.2    1
    14.0    1607279535.2    1
    9.3     1607279544.5    1
    12.7    1607279557.2    1
    8.6     1607279565.8    1
    12.0    1607279577.8    1
    8.4     1607279586.2    1
    11.8    1607279598.0    1
    8.5     1607279606.5    1
```

Input data generation:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.1f' % x)
delay = [10.0,10.1,14,9.3,12.7,8.6,12.0,8.4,11.8,8.5]
df = pd.DataFrame(delay)
df = df.rename(columns = {0: 'time_interval'})

time_stamp = 0
time_stamp = time.time()
    
index_time = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    update = time_stamp+row['time_interval']
    time_stamp = update
    index_time.append(update)
    
df['index_time'] = pd.DataFrame(index_time).astype(float)
df['flag'] = 1
```

My code:

```
i = 0
sequence = True
while sequence:
    if df['index_time'][i] > time.time():
        time.sleep(1)
    elif df['index_time'][i] < time.time() and df['flag'][i] == 1:
        df['flag'][i] = 2
        print("index_time:",df['index_time'][i],"flag:",df['flag'][i])
    elif df['index_time'].max() < time.time() and df['flag'][i] == 2:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular requirement, loop is not required. Use `np.where` to find the index positions and then perform the operation on the index positions obtained.

Try this:

```
id = df.index[np.where(df['index_time'] < time.time())]
df.loc[id,'flag'] = 2
```

**Note:**
You should not be using `iterrows()` to modify while iterating. Iterating is meant for reading and the iterator returns a copy of the original object (a view), thus the changes will not reflect on the original object.
Read [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

If you really want to use loop, then try `df.apply` and perform operations. See below,

```
def func(x):
    if x['index_time'] <= time.time():
        x['flag'] = 2
    return x
df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks! _index_time_ is increasing into the future with _time_interval_, so when the current time _time.time()_ is passing the _index_time_ i want to run an operation on that particlar row. Your example filters and returns the whole dataframe each the time. i dont seem to get the logic to work. (sorry cant use comment field properly and ctrl+k does not work) 

    def func(x):
        if x['index_time'] <= time.time() and x['flag'] == 1:
            print(x['index_time'])
            x['flag'] = 2
        return x

    df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)

Comment: df.apply works on each row individually. Not sure why it wont work for you.

Comment: What i am trying is a check every 100 ms whether there is a row with index_time  smaller than the current time, then process that row, otherwise wait 100 ms and check again until all index_times are checked. your suggestion is very usefull, but it did not automate it.

Comment: hi again, in fact it worked! i wrapped the code i posted above in a function and then applied your suggestion `df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)` and it worked. The only thing is that it prints the first row two times (can you see why?). the rest is fine!